# Jetty does not remove timed-out session, if the session was replaced in runtime

Tags: java, session, jetty, session-state, session-timeout

In the application, we use to switch sessions once the user mode is changed.

So basically we have something like this:

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
request.getSession(true);
```

Now happens the problem: after timeout, the session is not removed. After debugging some internal code, I found out that in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSession.timeout()` the session is not removed if `_requests > 0`. And the `_requests` is greater then zero, since in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(String, Request, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` the `complete()` runs on the `access` session is increased and the same session is decreased, even if during the invocation the actual session was replaced!

Did anyone experience the same problem and managed to solve it?

*Updated*: I created a workaround. See accepted answer below.

*Updated*: Bug in Jersey Community: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377610

Comment: Which session manager are you working with here?  hash, jdbc, mongodb, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem, by overriding the SessionHandler:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler;

public class MySessionHandler extends SessionHandler {

    @Override
    public void doScope(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession(false);
        super.doScope(target, baseRequest, request, response);
        HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(false);

        if (newSession != null && oldSession != newSession) {
            getSessionManager().complete(newSession);
        }
    }
}
```

In the application's context:

```
<Set name="sessionHandler">
     <New class="*************.MySessionHandler">
     </New>
</Set>
```